# How do I change which desktop environment loads with the `startx` command in the Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I installed CentOS 7.2 x64 on a laptop and then was able to successfully install the Cinnamon desktop environment. I'm interested in experimenting with various desktop environments. I attempted to install KDE (seems successful) and have enjoyed using it in the past:

```
yum -y groups install "KDE Plasma Workspaces" 
echo "exec startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc
startx
```

However `startx` still loads the Cinnamon desktop environment.

How do I change which desktop environment loads with the `startx` command in the Linux terminal?

Comment: What's the content of your `.xinitrc`? You just appended the new command. Did you remove the command to start Cinnamon before that?

Comment: @Aki No, that is all I did. So that command adds but does not remove xinitrc? Is this a file somewhere that needs to be edited or a command I can type?

Comment: `>>` appends, `>` overwrites. Yes, `.xinitrc` is a file in your home directory (`~` is the shortcut command for the current user's home, `~john/` resolves to `/home/john/` etc). You can edit the file using the editor of your choice, e.g. `nano ~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: @Aki Thank you! Please post that as an answer so I can accept it since you're the *first* one to help me get past the last point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, with `>>` you just append to the end of your `.xinitrc` file. If you previously used another desktop environment, the previous start command is still present. You can edit the file with the editor of your choice, e.g. `nano ~/.xinitrc`, and remove the corresponding line for Cinnamon or for easy switching between different environments just comment it out.